# cant save radio button selections to database with thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I have form and inside I have radio button option  , I have the controller class  and the model. I can successfully save the other data but radio buttons options reflects to database as 0 always.  I believe there is something wrong with thymeleaf radio button implementation.

```
<form id="add" role="form" th:action="@{/add}" method="post" th:object="${radiobutton}">
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>is it new</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadiosInline1" id="optionsRadiosInline1"
                   value="true" th:checked="*{isNew}"/>Yes
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadiosInline1" id="optionsRadiosInline2"
                   value="false" th:checked="*{isNew} == false"/>No
        </label>
    </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found it , values should be 0 or 1 instead of true and  false

```
<form id="add" role="form" th:action="@{/add}" method="post" th:object="${radiobutton}">
    <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>is it new</label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadiosInline1" id="optionsRadiosInline1" value="1"
                   th:checked="*{isNew}"/>Yes
        </label>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadiosInline1" id="optionsRadiosInline2" value="0"
                   th:checked="*{isNew} == false"/>No
        </label>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Lucky me. Found it after 2 hours of blood and sweat. Thanks for sharing. Up-voting.!